# Editing rendering of Lookup Field - XLST

Tags: list-view, lookup-column, xslt

Let's say I have a simple text column named MyCustomName with four fields in it:

```
REMOVE one
REMOVE two
three
REMOVE four
```

...and I want them to display like

```
one
two
three
four
```

in my list View. In order to do that I edit the View's XSLT code and come up with the following template:

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_Text_body.MyCustomName" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" match ="FieldRef[@Name='MyCustomName']" mode="Text_body" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@AutoHyperLink='TRUE'">
            <span>
                <xsl:if test="contains($thisNode/@MyCustomName, 'REMOVE')" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($thisNode/@MyCustomName, 'REMOVE'), substring-after($thisNode/@MyCustomName, 'REMOVE'))" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="not(contains($thisNode/@MyCustomName, 'REMOVE'))" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Now this works fine and my elements get rendered as I intended. However, what if the column is not a simple Text Column but a Lookup Column? My code doesn't seem to work in that case, what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it a bit differently and finally it works, code if anybody had similar problem:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[(@Encoded) and @Name='MyCustomColumn']" priority="10" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" mode="Lookup_body" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="contains(normalize-space($thisNode/@MyCustomColumn), 'REMOVE')" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name], 'REMOVE'), substring-after($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name], 'REMOVE'))" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(contains(normalize-space($thisNode/@MyCustomColumn), 'REMOVE'))" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```